# Checkout fails with a "Malformed network data" message

Tags: svn

I'm trying to make a checkout by command line:

```
svn co svn://dev.mycompany.com/backend/trunk
```

but the server say's::

```
svn: E210004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://dev.mycompany.com/backend/trunk'
svn: E210004: Malformed network data
```

I'm checked out this before, by eclipse. Maybe is a version issue, my client is 1.7.6. And the svn version is 1.6.3.

Comment: What are you using to checkout the repository? Tortoise? Command Line? What is syntax you are using to connect to the URL(i.e does it have a ':' or space in it?

Have you been successful checking out this repository before?

Comment: command line, the same as explain in the question i don't have spaces.